# Echo wordpress page title into onsubmit

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a single contact form the runs through the footer of every page on my site.

I have got the page title to echo out using `wp_title` but it is appearing before the form rather than in the string.

```
$html .= sprintf( '<form onsubmit="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'newsletter\', \'submitted\', \'' . wp_title('') . '\')" %s>', $atts ) . "\n";
```

It appears like this:

[image]

Comment: what you want to say i don't understand what is title in this form Free HR Advice share some code ??

Comment: @RaviSharma I would like to echo the wordpress page title into an onsubmit this is what the code above currently outputs onsubmit="ga('send', 'event', 'newsletter', 'submitted', ' ')" and the page title echos out above the form as shown in the image.

Comment: :- I want code you used for ga function. mention it in your question description.

Comment: @RaviSharma it's in the question, that is all that is controlling the form tag. The wp_title is default wordpress function

Comment: onsubmit you are calling a function named "ga" what code you have written in this function ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/):

**Your code**

```
wp_title( string $sep = '&raquo;', bool $display = true, string $seplocation = '' )
```

secod parameter determines if the title will be echoed or returned, in Your case you should set $display parameter to false.

**Solution:**

```
$html .= sprintf( '<form onsubmit="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'newsletter\', \'submitted\', \'' . wp_title('', false) . '\')" %s>', $atts ) . "\n";
```